# How to use stripe connect payment gateway with node.js?

Tags: node.js

Any one please give me some brief idea about how to use stripe with node.js. Any sample code please. Any help will be appreciated. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the Node Version of the **Stripe Library** in their official documentation:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/node

Apart from the official docs, there's a Github repo for **Stripe Nodejs Library**

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to Stripe API using this node package [Stripe Node.js Library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stripe)

It provides convenient access to the Stripe API from applications written in server-side JavaScript.